# How to generate '.form' file in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `.java` file. I need to generate a `.form` file using the `.java` file. When I write a `.java` file then automatically a `.form` file should be created. By using java *Swing*, how can we create a `.form` file?

Comment: What's a '.form' file? Sounds framework- or IDE-specific to me!? Please add more information and/or add additional tags.

Comment: .form file is a design view of java file in Sun Java studio enterprise8.0 IDE.  for a file in java swings we have both .java file and .form file. In .form file there is design related to our java file. If we delete .form file we can't see the design. Now the problem is If i run .java file automatically .form file should be created..

Comment: Jetbrains IDEA has this feature, it's called "Create Form Snapshot"

Answer (score 3):

Your question is as vague as they get, but usually it's the other way around - you generate java code from a form file created by a GUI designer such as NetBeans Matisse, Eclipse Jigloo or IntelliJ IDEA Forms Designer. Although they all use the `.forms` extension, the internal format differs wildly on different IDEs - it's generally some XML markup that's later used to generate Java code related to the GUI layout, so you wouldn't have to code it yourself. I find it hard to believe you want to generate form files from an existing layout.

As far as I know Sun Java Studio Enterprise is based on NetBeans, so probably your GUI designer is Matisse. There is no way to regenerate the form from the Java code (at least nothing short of you writing some tool to parse the code in the `initComponents()` method, which will be a start, but not enough to get everything back). As @gnoupi pointed out, in the other question you posted, your best bet would be to read the existing source and restore the form based on it. All this of course assumes that you're not using version control and there is no way to restore the project's missing form file from there.

Comment: It's probably because the form file got deleted in the meantime, and now the user needs to change the layout. Without the form file, it's nearly impossible (especially if using a GroupLayout).

Comment: Besides, you are not answering the question, so this should remain a comment.

Comment: @Gnoupi - this is probably the best possible answer for this question.

Comment: I'm a professional Swing developer - I'm fairly aware what is possible and what is not is Swing ;-) If he deleted the form and doesn't use a VCS it's fairly hard to recover. Tools like IntelliJ allow you to capture the layout a Swing form at runtime and generate a IntelliJ designer specific form it, but without any more info about the particular IDE I cannot say more. I use MigLayout ever for the most complex layouts, few real swing devs would opt for a GUI designer at all - it limits you too much and generates a lot of ugly code...

Comment: im using java studio enterprise 8 IDE. can i generate using this IDE??

Comment: "I'm a professional Swing developer", well, good for you, so am I (though I have experience only with Matisse, good to know about InelliJ's capacity to create a form from an existing layout). What you wrote as comment now is a possible answer, but not what you actually answered. You were only explaining forms, and questioning the user's need with "I find it hard to believe".

Comment: Didn't mean it in a offensive way, mate. I was irritated partly by the behavior of the user that asked the question two times instead of providing details here. I've updated my answer, featuring your answer from the other question.